# Show subsection & subsubsection numbers in titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I don't get the proper numbers using `titlesec` for subsection & subsubsection. If I remove the `titlesec` they are displayed.
**Here is the output**

[image: Numbers not shown]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Burgundy}{HTML}{800020}
%-------------Title Chap & Section------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\Large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat
{\chapter}  % command
[display]   % shape
{\HUGE\bfseries\color{Burgundy}\raggedleft}      % format
{\thechapter}         % label
{20pt}       % separation between label and chapter-title
{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}]    % before-code

\titleformat
{\section}                       % command
[block]                        % shape
{\Large\bfseries\color{Burgundy}\raggedleft}      % format
{\thesection}                    % label
{0.5em}                           % separation between label and chapter-title
{\Large}[\vspace{1ex}]  % before-code

\newcommand{\HUGE}{\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont} % (the first number is the pt size of the font, the second number the space in pts between lines: this becomes the value of \baselineskip)

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{.7\baselineskip}%{6ex}{4ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{.7\baselineskip}%{6ex}{4ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{.7\baselineskip}%{6ex}{4ex}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `titlesec`, use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` to tell it how deep you want it to number. Default might be chapter+section. Note you seem to have a bug in you settigns for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` as you ask it to use the same counter as `\section`

Comment: @daleif I spotted the error! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided by `@daleif` the error consists in naming the subsection & subsubsection with the name `\thesection`

insted of this

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
```

it should be

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesubsection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesubsubsection.}{0.5em}{}
```